# JavaScript calling Aspx

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am a php developer (I am also well versed in c#), I've been tasked with converted one of our pages from php to aspx. This site consists of 2 pages. One is the main html page and the other is a php file that has a javascript function which creates our menu.

from the main page I can say

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.php"></script>
```

and in the menu.php i have my javascript/php

```
<?
//php function
function doPHPstuff() { return "Hello World"; }
?>

//javascript
 function create_menu()
{
    var base = '';
        document.write('<table cellpadding="0" cellspaceing="0" border="0" style="width:98%"><tr>' +
//php code within the javascript 
alert('<?=doPHPsutff()?>');

}
```

I have rewritten the "php stuff" as aspx code (c#) but am now sure how to call it? Is there a simple way to do it like in php?

Answer (score 1):

You use `<%= %>` instead of `<?= ?>` if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I tried creating a aspx file the same way i did the php one with the correct <% %> but when i call my javascript function create_menu nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the code do, and when it runs. Please provide more information about that. But basically:

1- You can call `__doPostBack` to retrieve the value

2- You can print the code to the aspx page, just like in php `alert("<%= myCodeBehindMethod(); %>");` (not a recommended practice)

3- You can set it as a web service and call with a normal ajax request

4- Or you can register with script manager:

```
protected myMethod()
{
   string myVariable = "hello";
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(page,page.getType(),"name","alert("+ myVariable +");")
}
```

**edit:** reply to comment

You can't call a aspx as if it was a javascript file. You can call a function in the aspx, referring to a function in js, however. Example:

script.js :

```
function myFun(param)
{
    alert(param);
}
```

page.aspx.cs:

```
protected string myMethod()
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

page.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFun(<%=myMethod() %>); //will alert Hello World!
</script>
```

Comment: the code behind is reading a csv file and outputting its contents in a table. when i reference the file in the main page

Comment: with <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.aspx"></script> it doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: so, if i am understanding you correctly, this is something that cannot be done with 1 page, I need to have a cs file and a codebehind tag. When i did that it seemed to work. I was hoping to have 1 aspx page and no codebehind cs file...

Comment: Well, it is possible. You can have `<script language="C#" runat="server"> </script>` or `<% %>` and run some c# code. But you really shouldn't. One of the good things in .net is separation from the logic (aspx.cs) and presentation(aspx), so it a bad practice.